# Turn off org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping detectHandlers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to turn off org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping detectHandlers , I put spring 3 startup in debug mode, and I see all classes call 'detectHandlers'

example

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping detectHandlers org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:86)] - Rejected bean name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': no URL paths identified

[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping detectHandlers org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:86)] - Rejected bean name 'systemProperties': no URL paths identified

[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping detectHandlers org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:86)] - Rejected bean name 'systemEnvironment': no URL paths identified
```

only my "controller" classes have handlers and all other classes do not have. I'm trying to speed up spring startup. Anyway to turn off this auto detect handler feature for every class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip unneccessary classes [using filters](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters):

```
<beans>

   <context:component-scan base-package="org.example">
      <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression=".*NotControllerBean"/>
   </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

The most perfomant and clear solution for me is move controllers to dedicated package and use only this package for component scan.

Comment: can configure DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping in xml to exclude scan every bean not through componenet-scan exclude?

Answer (score 1):

"only my "controller" classes have handlers and all other classes do not have"

You are right. And In order to know if a class is a controller Spring has to check it. And that's exactly what you see here: Spring is looking for the presence of `@Controller` or `@RequestMapping` on the type level.